PL/SQL block throwing a "variables not bound" error despite seemingly no errors in the code
I've been looking at my code for a while and searching for any syntax errors that may be causing the problem but I really can't find it anywhere. I'm running the script in Oracle Autonomous Database and tried it on the Live SQL but it won't run on both.
Code is:
VARIABLE b_basic_percent NUMBER
VARIABLE b_pf_percent NUMBER

DECLARE
    v_today DATE := SYSDATE;
    v_tomorrow v_today%TYPE;
BEGIN
    v_tomorrow := v_today + 1;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TODAY IS : ' || v_today);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('TOMORROW IS ' || v_tomorrow);

    :b_basic_percent := 45;
    :b_pf_percent := 12;
END;
/

PRINT b_basic_percent
PRINT b_pf_percent

I've tried removing the whitespaces between the ":=" and values but I don't think it's significant.

VARIABLE and PRINT are SQL*Plus commands and work on the client application that you are using to connect to the database and do NOT work on the database itself. If you are using a client that support SQL*Plus commands then your code will work; however, if your client does not support SQL*Plus commands then it will not work.

I copied your code, as is, to our web interface for Autonomous in Oracle Cloud...it works.

It's not working in LiveSQL because the VARIABLE and PRINT commands aren't supported. However, we're about to update LiveSQL to use the same technology as I show in the above screenshot, so it will work there as well, soon.
Please update your question to show more details, like the actual errors/problems encountered when running your script.

Is that so? Could it also be the case for Apex? That 's where I've been running it

That's your problem, APEX uses the same sql execution/runtime path as LIveSQL - it's not supported there. Use Database Actions/SQL Developer Web for the best web client when you want to query/interact with your database.

Got it. Thanks for the help!
